# Xamarin (iOS and Android) side menu panel

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

Im new in Xamarin, for the last couple of days i've been doing some searching on Side menu panel that supports both Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android and can include an image at the top of it like the screenshot shown below.
[Side menu screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QeH3.png)
Any components in mind? if there is no component how can i do it by myself?

Answer (score 0):

Android has the Navigation Draw for side slide out menus.

For iOS there are quite a few components such as Flyout Navigation, ActionTray and Sidebar Navigation

Comment: Yes, been over these components the thing is do they support the outline as the same one i just attached. like the header image and customizing colors so on.